# jQuery mobile application freezes sometimes on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The application has some $.post jquery ajax requests to populate the DOM and some big images. The application freezes half the time on localhost and i can't seem to isolate the problem. What are usually causes for a behaviour such as this?

Thank you!

Comment: how many images are you loading and how big are they?

Comment: About 20, lets say full screen size. thing is. when i dont load em, other things cause the site to freeze. is there some memory limit to PHP's localhost server? cause when i use mamp or when the site is online then i dont have this problem